# changing white backgroud in clip-path

Tags: css, clip-path

Is it possible to change the color of the white background that remains in chrome after applying the clip-path?

i have tried the background-clip method and some adjustment in css as i have seen other doubts

```
.header {
height: 100vh;
background-image: 
linear-gradient(to right bottom, 
rgba(204, 227, 233, 0.8),
rgba(6, 6, 7, 0.3)),   

background-repeat: round;
background-position: inherit;
position: relative;
background-clip: black;
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 60vh, 0 100%);
}
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background colour of a parent element. For example:

```css
.header-container {
  background-color: black;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right bottom,
    rgba(204, 227, 233, 0.8),
    rgba(6, 6, 7, 0.3)
  );
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 60vh, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="header"></div>
</div>
```